# `fill` scale is not shown in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my dummy code:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(xx=sample(10,6), 
                 yy=sample(10,6), 
                 type2=c('a','b','a','a','b','b'),
                 type3=c('A','C','B','A','B','C')
                 )
ggplot(data=df, mapping = aes(x=xx, y=yy)) + 
geom_point(aes(shape=type3, fill=type2), size=5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(24,25,21)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('green', 'red'))
```

Resulting plot has a legend but it's 'type2' section doesn't reflect scale of `fill` value - is it by design?

[image: sample plot]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but I ran into this exact problem and want to post this here for others like me. While the accepted answer works, the less risky, cleaner method is:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, mapping = aes(x=xx, y=yy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=type3, fill=type2), size=5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(24,25,21)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(a='green',b='red'))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=21)))
```

The key is to change the shape in the legend to one of those that can have a 'fill'.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a different workaround.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, mapping = aes(x=xx, y=yy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=type3, fill=type2), size=5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(24,25,21)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(a='green',b='red'))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=c(a="green",b="red"))))
```

[image]

Using `guide_legend(...)` with `override_aes` is a way to influence the appearance of the guide (the legend). The hack is that here we are "overriding" the fill colors in the guide with the colors they should have had in the first place.

Comment: wow, what a hack indeed! I would never guess myself :) Thanks!

Comment: This is a nice workaround. I learned `override_aes` from this. Thank you and plus one.

Comment: ggplot has so many things I never think of, like this `override_aes`. Great post!

Answer (score 2):

I played with the data and came up with this idea. I first assigned shape in the first `geom_point`. Then, I made the shapes empty. In this way, outlines stayed in black colour. Third, I manually assigned specific shape. Finally, I filled in the symbols.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=xx, y=yy)) +
geom_point(aes(shape = type3), size = 5.1) + # Plot with three types of shape first
scale_shape(solid = FALSE) + # Make the shapes empty
scale_shape_manual(values=c(24,25,21)) + # Assign specific types of shape
geom_point(aes(color = type2, fill = type2, shape = type3), size = 4.5)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this workaround is acceptable for this simplified example. But more generally it is not ideal solution - for example, I can't control the outline of symbols (black, on my original plot) anymore.

Comment: In addition, when I do something else with the legend, for example, modify caption by adding `+ guides(color=guide_legend(title='My title'))` - it makes 3 section on the legend instead of 2

Comment: @VasilyA I have tried a couple of things. I suggested an alternative idea. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @jazzuro, thank you for your efforts. Unfortunately for my real case your second workaround (btw, maybe you could put it to separate answer?) is also not an ideal solution because I have more points and symbols inside circles become very hard to distinguish :/ 
And overall, I still don't understand why the `fill` is not shown in normal way - it looks like a bug for me...

Comment: @VasilyA I see. This may not be that different, but how about this one? `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=xx, y=yy)) + geom_point(aes(shape = type3), size = 5) + geom_point(color = "red", size=4.5)` ggplot uses circles for the second geom_point. If we can specify shape here, that would be probably what you are after.

Comment: @VasilyA This is almost there except colour. `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=xx, y=yy)) + geom_point(aes(shape = type3), size = 5) +
geom_point(aes(shape = type3),color = "red", size=4.5)`

Comment: @VasilyA I updated my suggestion again. This is probably what you are after.

Comment: well, for some reasons (in case of complex plot with many other elements) I would prefer to avoid drawing the points second time, but otherwise it's indeed looking like good solution. Thanks! 
(I will just wait few days before accepting your answer, in hope that somebody propose more 'native' variant).

Comment: @VasilyA There may be a straightforward way of doing this. Let's hope someone can suggest another way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you want looks like this?

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=xx,y=yy))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=type3,color=type2,fill=type2),size=5)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(24,25,21))
```

[image: Ggplot fill-color-shape]

Comment: yes, this was the very first solution proposed by @jazzurro, and (I'll quote myself) this workaround is acceptable for this simplified example, but more generally it is not ideal solution - for example, I can't control the outline of symbols (black, on my original plot) anymore.