# How to get point outline in one colour and point fill in another colour in ggtern (Rstudio)?

Tags: r, colors, fill, ternary, ggtern

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE77p.jpg)

I'm working with the ggtern package, trying to create ternary diagrams. 
I want to be able to distinguish "Growthzone" and "SpotPosition" by assigning separate colours representing "Growthzone" for point outlines, and separate colours representing "SpotPosition" as point fill.

I recall in ggplot2 I could use "colour" for the outline and "fill" for the fill, but in ggtern both "colour" and "fill" seem to refer to fill.

Is there a different command I can use, or a way to work around this? Or a fault in my code?

```html
Type = ALL$Type
Origin=ALL$Mount
Growthzone=ALL$GZ
LABELS=ALL$Run
ClastID=ALL$Clast_ID
SpotPosition=ALL$in_growth_section


DATA <- data.frame(An = ALL$XAn, Ab = ALL$Xab, 
Or = ALL$Xor, label = sprintf("%s", LABELS))
show(DATA)


plot <- ggtern(data = DATA, 
               mapping = aes(An, Ab, Or)) +
theme_rgbg() +  
  geom_mask() + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=Growthzone, shape=ClastID, fill=SpotPosition))+

scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow")) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "blue", "green", "darkgreen", "magenta"))+
scale_shape_manual(values = c(2))+ 
 
  #tweak guides
  guides(shape= guide_legend(order   =1,
                             override.aes=list(size=5)),
         size = guide_legend(order   =2))


last_plot()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uf27.png)

Comment: Try changing your `scale_shape_manual` value to one that has options for a different fill and colour e.g. a value between 21 and 25. See for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683854/colors-lost-in-legend-when-using-scale-shape-manual

Comment: Understanding ggplot2 will answer this question. meenaparam above is right, you need to use shapes that allow you to map both colour and fill.