# R: geom jitter legend does not show color and shape

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add jittered points which are colored by one column and shape is another column. But I would also like them to have a black border. Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes_string('Dim1', 'Dim2', fill = 'group', shape = 'library_type')) +
  geom_jitter(size = 5, width = 0.5, height = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 21:22)
```

and this is the data

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Dim1 = c(2.2433841103276, -1.0303647643367, -4.63257218659317, 
12.7725858563145, -16.4870472079555, -5.89065982163346, -0.985970986489414, 
1.69578384100998, -2.33323980629837, 10.970166193839, 10.2024221295079, 
-10.6379213458339, 6.61075352370346, 1.812275158759, 10.2678441876134, 
-4.67706157029068, -10.9628763324062, 2.37916063010299, -2.14151717484391, 
6.17873762785995, 1.43081234633529, 1.32741938769424, -0.509525430802464, 
-4.41292716324723, 1.60391901671493, -15.1547632342616, 13.4221372479161, 
-4.37019587815201, -3.27147628128922, -4.56963254273331, 8.39020632445419, 
-4.44982148468888, 6.13996790587509, -4.35541678727066, -4.45309068024552, 
-4.8850178843776, -4.67206240952408, 10.6344032162389, 1.2055765265187, 
-6.33491040528214, 2.35641406714523, -1.22826982796585, 1.76740847766006, 
-2.20920897782242, -9.84016133606827, -5.30173302948868, 2.48082064330185, 
1.54127036273086, 2.07977007567489, -5.39448262513077), Dim2 = c(3.98269763950216, 
12.0263954735171, -4.84496339794291, 1.20136013988363, 1.08652106288778, 
-4.31233819957865, 11.9845406151186, 4.15871826175558, -9.5392115974058, 
-2.74255188938273, -0.358736511432059, -15.3434594535459, -12.2606137656797, 
4.04486766818868, -0.198577952217735, -4.82197031017435, -5.17211183544291, 
4.69237771991598, 17.0735327339541, 7.17819610599386, -16.039408054315, 
-15.9196313285459, -2.41221126552714, -13.5231040382017, -16.2335446738829, 
-10.523520793878, 1.19396928314077, -13.5673793220152, 5.73542228702413, 
-4.86651166912211, 4.80452457431661, -4.84282478328837, 7.13171783450948, 
-13.5823205375303, -4.81453689571512, -4.70398124691141, -4.82535823818339, 
-0.404572960101492, -15.9311927222837, 1.63539258006918, 4.59739128116476, 
12.1994825935732, 4.11349931720602, -9.66564210888041, 0.843212757147424, 
-4.86665901180399, -4.42825731273783, -15.8932298087705, 3.73198262218343, 
-4.54381355281962), sample_id = c("SRR1068687", "SRR1068788", 
"SRR1068808", "SRR1068832", "SRR1068855", "SRR1068880", "SRR1068905", 
"SRR1068929", "SRR1068953", "SRR1068977", "SRR1068999", "SRR1069024", 
"SRR1069048", "SRR1069074", "SRR1069097", "SRR1069121", "SRR1069141", 
"SRR1069166", "SRR1069188", "SRR1069209", "SRR1069231", "SRR1069255", 
"SRR1069279", "SRR1069303", "SRR1069328", "SRR1069352", "SRR1069376", 
"SRR1069400", "SRR1069421", "SRR1069445", "SRR1069466", "SRR1069490", 
"SRR1069514", "SRR1069539", "SRR1069564", "SRR1069590", "SRR1069614", 
"SRR1069638", "SRR1069666", "SRR1069690", "SRR1069714", "SRR1069734", 
"SRR1069758", "SRR1069778", "SRR1069802", "SRR1069826", "SRR1069850", 
"SRR1069871", "SRR1069895", "SRR1069919"), batch = c("GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", 
"GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A", "GTEx_poly-A"), 
    study_id = c("GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", 
    "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", 
    "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", 
    "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", 
    "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", 
    "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", 
    "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx", "GTEx"), library_type = c("poly-A", 
    "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", 
    "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", 
    "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", 
    "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", 
    "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", 
    "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", 
    "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", 
    "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", "poly-A", 
    "poly-A"), group = c("Esophagus", "Testis", "Skin", "Blood Vessel", 
    "Muscle", "Skin", "Testis", "Esophagus", "Stomach", "Breast", 
    "Breast", "Blood", "Skin", "Esophagus", "Adipose Tissue", 
    "Skin", "Liver", "Stomach", "Brain", "Prostate", "Esophagus", 
    "Esophagus", "Thyroid", "Spleen", "Esophagus", "Pancreas", 
    "Blood Vessel", "Spleen", "Adrenal Gland", "Skin", "Uterus", 
    "Skin", "Prostate", "Spleen", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Adipose Tissue", 
    "Esophagus", "Heart", "Stomach", "Testis", "Esophagus", "Stomach", 
    "Heart", "Skin", "Colon", "Esophagus", "Esophagus", "Skin"
    )), row.names = c("SRR1068687", "SRR1068788", "SRR1068808", 
"SRR1068832", "SRR1068855", "SRR1068880", "SRR1068905", "SRR1068929", 
"SRR1068953", "SRR1068977", "SRR1068999", "SRR1069024", "SRR1069048", 
"SRR1069074", "SRR1069097", "SRR1069121", "SRR1069141", "SRR1069166", 
"SRR1069188", "SRR1069209", "SRR1069231", "SRR1069255", "SRR1069279", 
"SRR1069303", "SRR1069328", "SRR1069352", "SRR1069376", "SRR1069400", 
"SRR1069421", "SRR1069445", "SRR1069466", "SRR1069490", "SRR1069514", 
"SRR1069539", "SRR1069564", "SRR1069590", "SRR1069614", "SRR1069638", 
"SRR1069666", "SRR1069690", "SRR1069714", "SRR1069734", "SRR1069758", 
"SRR1069778", "SRR1069802", "SRR1069826", "SRR1069850", "SRR1069871", 
"SRR1069895", "SRR1069919"), class = "data.frame")
```

The plot that is generated, looks good but the legend does not show the corresponding colors:

[image]

How do I change the legend such that it shows the colors and the shape?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`fill\` scale is not shown in the legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221011/fill-scale-is-not-shown-in-the-legend)

Comment: Specifically, the problem is that while the points on the graph have a shape that supports a fill aesthetic, the points on the legend don't. If you override the legend points to a shape that can have a fill, the colours show up.

Comment: I was able to use this comment https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2322#issuecomment-342418340 to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use this comment github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2322#issuecomment-342418340 to fix the issue.